# SharePoint Multilingual

Tags: sharepoint, multilingual

We have a SharePoint document management site and the documents will be uploaded from java portal, via SharePoint web services.

The metadata values will be provided multi language (Like Spanish).

Is it safe to  accept and store such data in SharePoint as SQL server uses unique code format to store the SharePoint data in SQL server.

If storing the multilingual data in SharePoint is  not right approach,  is there any other way we can do it.

Please let us know your views if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this question is from 2013, I will base my answer on the On Premises versions of SharePoint.

From the description, it looks like the entry point for document to this document center is a Java portal that is probably in Spanish.  It looks like the concern is the data entry of metadata (such as Description etc.) is coming from a Spanish based interface.  It is quite possible that the hosting servers are also running with Language Packs (such as Spanish) installed.  As such, it is possible for the user to enter and produce characters that do no appear in the English language and that is what concerns the original poster.  The poster is correct in that SharePoint uses SQL Server as its back end data store, however, both the SharePoint and SQL Server products are (at least now) language agnostic.  If you can produce the text and the Java interface correctly encodes said text, then there is no cause for concern.  The data will be stored with full fidelity in SharePoint and by proxy SQL Server regardless of the host's language pack configuration.

In short, it's OK to do.